# Is there a way to shorten deploy commands while using Shopify theme kit, can a script be created for this without using webpack or some other package?

Tags: deployment, shopify, config

I am using theme kit to deploy to specific environments specified within config.yml but the deploy commands are becoming quite lengthy and potential risky if not typed in correctly. I was hoping to be able to have shortcuts for these similar to what exists within a `package.json` in webpack. For example, to deploy to multiple live themes and also to not delete files I have to use a command that looks like: `theme deploy --allow-live -n -e=prod-us -e=prod-uk`.

I was hoping to be able to shorten this command without using a tool like webpack which would introduce a ton of unnecessary complexity into the code. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You use Webpack? Wow. Throwback to the good old days of waiting 2 minutes for a build instead of 1 second with something else, anything else, like ESBuild...